# error C2665, can't resolve between 2 overloads for System::Windows::Forms::TextRenderer::DrawText

Tags: c++-cli, drawtext

`Windows::Forms::TextRenderer::DrawText(gT, numTo100, sfo, Rectangle(2, 2, 12, 12), SystemColors::ControlText);`

is giving the error

> 1>error C2665: 'System::Windows::Forms::TextRenderer::DrawText' : none of the 8 overloads could convert all the argument types
>
> 1> could be 'void System::Windows::Forms::TextRenderer::DrawText(System::Drawing::IDeviceContext ^,System::String ^,System::Drawing::Font ^,System::Drawing::Point,System::Drawing::Color)'
>
> 1>or       'void System::Windows::Forms::TextRenderer::DrawText(System::Drawing::IDeviceContext ^,System::String ^,System::Drawing::Font ^,System::Drawing::Rectangle,System::Drawing::Color)'

If I lose the line I get no errors. I've tried it the other way with Point and it was working fine in my other project. Any ideas would be appreciated, thanks.

**EDIT**
Here are the pertinent preceeding lines, FWIW..

```
    System::Drawing::Font sfo(FontFamily::GenericSansSerif, 8.0F, FontStyle::Bold);
```

Comment: gT->DrawString(numTo100, %sfo, Drawing::Brushes::Indigo, 2, 2);
 is working but I dislike unneccessary floats and I must admit I wasn't aware of non-static methods for text rendering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've created your `Font` object using stack semantics, so in order to pass it to a function wanting a tracking handle (`Font^`), you need to use unary `operator%`, much as you would use unary `operator&` to get an object pointer from an object value in C++:

```cpp
Windows::Forms::TextRenderer::DrawText(
    gT,
    numTo100,
    %sfo,
    Rectangle(2, 2, 12, 12),
    SystemColors::ControlText
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the Rectangle class parameter is the good one ?

```
Windows::Forms::TextRenderer::DrawText(gT, numTo100, sfo, System::Drawing::Rectangle(2, 2, 12, 12), SystemColors::ControlText);
```

This usually happens when some arguments are implicitly cast but many ways are the target type are  found.